# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass on my style tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` when I load my rails 4 app the error shows on this line.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

When I remove the style tag and javascript tag the page loads fine. I am using rails 4.

Comment: Well, must be some faulty ERB inside your css or js.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please.

Comment: paste the whole error

Comment: the was not compatible with rails 5